How to disable italics for VSCode Github Copilot prompts?
I hope the code suggestions from GitHub Copilot in VSCode use normal font instead of italics. I’ve tried modifying the italic settings in the theme style configuration, but it doesn’t work for this.

are you talking about chat prompts? chat responses? inline suggestion (in the editor tabs) font?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
